# Wherever cursor.moveToFirst() is called it gives exceeded cursor quota will kill it

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-cursor, android-cursorloader

Wherever cursor.moveToFirst() is used  it throws the following error and this happens only in

**xiaomi phones**

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Process 29459 exceeded cursor quota 308, will kill it
```

and they crashes . 
I tried options like closing the cursor , limiting the number of rows returned by the cursor.
nothing helps .

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have closed the cursor like this

```
Cursor cursor = //yourstatement;
try {
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
       }
 }
} finally {
    cursor.close();
}
```